# programming examples of dsf(device simulation framework) in c# or vb.net

Tags: .net, hardware, wdk

I would like to program with device simulation framework  (dsf) which is included with the microsoft wdk(windows driver kit) in managed code anyone have any c# or vb.net source code samples i can see?  I am trying to convert my vbscript sample on http://kinecmultipoint.codeplex.com to vb.net but i cant figure out all of the types/classes for vb.net.
Anyone know what im doing wrong take a look at it but it has a blue screen error right now so run in virtual machine because i havent fixed the error yet. Also, having a debugged from the wdk installed will help during a bluescreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since fixed this error myself it turns out I have some minor errors (for loops not being done correctly) in my script file have cause this.
I will upload at the link above my latest source code.